# how to deploy the file "MY_PROGRAM_NAME.runtimeconfig.json"?

Tags: json, .net-core, deployment, .net-core-3.1, runtime-configuration

I've got this problem:
"Published .Net Core App Warns to Install .Net Core but it's Already Installed"

I searched on Stack Overflow and found the answer:

> In my case I had the same issue, and the problem was that I was not deploying the file "MY_PROGRAM_NAME.runtimeconfig.json". After copying this file, which is present in the build output, the application launches without any problem.

I don't know how to deploy this file, and I have to deploy the file .runtimeconfig.json in the app I use or in .Net Core 3.1 Runtime.

Comment: I just came across the same problem.  I think you just have to distribute it with your application